# iPad/iPhone Screen Mirror

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, airplay

I'm trying to figure out a way to mirror an iPad screen to other iPads. This doesn't seem to be supported on the platform though.

Basically, a teacher would have an iPad, then the students would have iPads and see everything that is happening on the teachers screen, but on their screens. 
Thoughts?

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mobile-presenter-pro-wireless/id363283163?mt=8 has "Screencast" so it's possible.

Comment: What have you tried?  It isn't (legally) possible to mirror the _entire_ iPad screen (including other apps) with the current APIs, and it would be inefficient to open a stream to potentially 40+ devices.

Answer (score 1):

I have been attempting to find a solution to this problem myself.  I have not found any apps that can mirror exactly what is happening on another IPAD, but some come close.

RabbleBrowser and Ideaflight both had potential.  Ideaflight appears to be more for business.  RabbleBrowser appears to allow the mirroring, except it only works as a browser and a file/picture mirroring.

Both iPads are linked to the same wifi and when you join a session, they will mirror the iPad that started session.  Also allows chat (controlled by session starter).

It does NOT continue to mirror if you move out of browser and into another app however.  I had dreams of leading a class through a a lesson on google earth, but no go .:(

Another option is attaching a laptop to a projector.  Then you download Airserver on the laptop.  Go to the menu bar at bottom of iPad and turn on AirPlay.  The laptop will mirror the iPad perfectly and project it!  It's wireless and works well.  I tried the HDMI connector to laptop but it gives a poor quality, shaky image.

Hope they allow mirroring in future updates.  The capability is there, don't know why they don't!  Guess trying to sell more appletv!

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked on the Apple forum (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3118281?start=0&tstart=0), and the following app seemed to help them or answer their question.

Have a look at Replicate Pro on the app store:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/replicate-pro-for-ipad/id363286515?mt=8

One feature listed in the notes:

> Share files between two iPads/iPhones that are running this app. (Pro
>   version only)

I'm not sure if this will cover multiple devices or simply between two, but it may be worth a look. Sadly, the only way to try would be to spend $5.99.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an application for the student iPad that emulates the screen of the teachers iPad. I would suggest that, although i dont know if its possible, the teacher somehow  starts up and app that emulates their entire iPad. Meaning, from within the app named "teacher share" (or whatever it is), they can access the music, settings,  notes and other apps found on their ipad. Then that information could be sent over a network to the students.

Answer (score 0):

Nearpod is an app that will allow you to mirror a presentation on several iPads.  I have had up to 9 at one time.  Through the Nearpod program you can make a presentation similar to PowerPoint, and also incorporate interactive questions, which can be multiple choice, short answer, and even drawings.  The only drawback is the full version costs $10/month.  The free version is still good, you are just limited on the size of the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

After doing lots of research, I found one app which shares iPhone device into another iPhone device. Really great logic they have applied for screen mirroring.

No idea about detailed how they have implemented but after installing and checking the app I came to know that I think they have used iPhone Screen Recording and broadcasting it on to their server and then on another device they are syncing from the same URL.

**OliOli** a free and simple screen sharing app for iOS.

**iOS App:** https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/olioli-screen-sharing/id1382253993?mt=8

**WebSite:** https://olioli.io/